# Resnet 50 as a backbone of Unet

Tags: keras, tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to use a pre trained Resnet 50 as a backbone for Unet model.
But the issue is resnet 50 is expecting the size of image as 197 x 197 3D channel but the image of mine is 128 X 128 x 1D channel. Is there any keras or tensorflow implementation on those.

Comment: You can always resize the image and repeat them 3 times over the third axis

Answer (score 1):

When you import ResNet50 import in this way:

```
image_input=Input(shape=(512, 512, 3))
model = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=False)
```

After that, you can work with your desired image_size